# Need Label SAP:NETWEAVER:702:EXPORT(1/3):*:*

Tags: abap

Hi I'm trying to install SAP Netweaver trial version - when I'm going to step2 to define parameters, it's asking some label -- Need Label SAP:NETWEAVER:702:EXPORT(1/3):*:*

Answer (score 0):

Do you have CD/DVDs ? If so look for this one and upload to your HardDisk and proced properly. If not look on service.sap.com and download it.